# How to connect xWiki and Azure AD for user authentication

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, xwiki

I'd like to connect my xWiki installation to Azure AD for user authentication. Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: did you end up resolving it? Looking to resolve the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the dedicated extension pages describing how to use LDAP in XWiki: http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/LDAP/ (both Authenticator and the Application to customize it)

Additionally, you might be interested in this paying app that is supposed to be specialized in Active Directory and should help you use it without too much work: https://store.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/ActiveDirectoryApplication

Now, since Azure AD does not allow LDAP connection (according to your comment), you might want to look into using OpenID Connect. It seems to be supported by Azure AD (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code) and XWiki also has a recently published extension to be able to authenticate with OpenID Connect (http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/OpenID+Connect/). There`s also an introductory blog article on the feature: https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Blog/Your%20new%20Identity%20Provider%20XWiki

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But Azure AD ist not accessible via LDAP from outside of Azure by default. So, it is rather OAuth 2.0 than LDAP access.

Comment: I`ve edited the above answer. You could try using OpenID Connect, seems to fit your need of connecting to Azure AD.

Comment: Did the above edit solve your problem (i.e. does OpenID Connect work on Azure AD)? Also, if it does, please remember to accept the answer :)